# SpringMVC+Thymeleaf ,error message is : template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I've read the other answers, but no matter，thanks

Spring:

```
<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring3</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.13</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "login.html", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you need a template resolver?

Try something like this:

```
<bean id="templateResolver"
      class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
 </bean>
```

Make sure that /path/after/web-inf/login.html is being returned by a Spring MVC controller.

Comment: Where should this go?

Answer (score 7):

You are likely missing the "suffix" property within the templateResolver configuration. It should be best practice to use both a path "prefix" (where the file is located) and a "suffix" (the file extension - otherwise thymeleaf tries to resolve just "login" w/o an extension) within the template resolver configuration. Like so:

```
<beans:bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
    <beans:property name="templateMode" value="HTML5"/>
    <beans:property name="cacheable" value="false"/> <!-- Development only -->
</beans:bean>
```

And requesting the login view within a controller does not include the file extension.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
public String login(HttpSession session) {
    // do stuff

    // Thymeleaf (delegated by springmvc) will request the "login" view at which 
    // point the prefix and suffix are added to resolve the template location. 
    return "login"; 
}
```

So based on this configuration and within a maven-based project, the login.html should be located at

```
${project_home}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/login.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe remove slash "/" in the controller request mapping will work.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "login")
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it turned out that thymeleaf html parser works poorly and doesn't accept one line html files. Formatting it solved the problem.